# when I implement indices into a mesh/face, why does it return an OpenGl error?

Tags: c++, opengl, c++17, glm-math, vertex

So I have a program that generates chunk-meshes based on given vertex data. I already have it working without indices, but upon trying to include them into my program, it returns OpenGL error 1285.

I have the arraybuffer and vao calls on different functions, but they look like this:

```
void Chunk::_loadArrayBuffers()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &_trianglesID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_uvsID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_normalsID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_IndiceID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _trianglesID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        _triangles.size() * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),
        _triangles.data(),
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _uvsID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        _uvs.size() * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat),
        _uvs.data(),
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalsID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        _normals.size() * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),
        _normals.data(),
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (_indices.size() * 3 > 0)
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _IndiceID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            _indices.size() * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),
            _indices.data(),
            GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


}


void Chunk::_makeVAO()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(_VAO);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _trianglesID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _uvsID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _normalsID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

For each mesh, I store the vertex data of each triangle into multiple glm::vec3s, essentially a vector of size 3. My rectangle/face creation function looks like this:

```
void Chunk::_addRectangle(glm::vec3 center, glm::vec3 height, glm::vec3 width, unsigned tex_num)
{
    if (glm::length(height) == 0 || glm::length(width) == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("width or height should not be 0");

    glm::vec3 corner1 = center - (height / 2.0) - (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner2 = center - (height / 2.0) + (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner3 = center + (height / 2.0) + (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner4 = center + (height / 2.0) - (width / 2.0);

    glm::vec3 normal = glm::cross(height, width);

    glm::vec2 uv1;
    glm::vec2 uv2;
    glm::vec2 uv3;
    glm::vec2 uv4;

    if (fabs(normal[1]) == 1.0)
    {
        uv1 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 1);
        uv2 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 0);
        uv3 = glm::vec2(0, 0);
        uv4 = glm::vec2(0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        uv1 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, height[1]);
        uv2 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 0);
        uv3 = glm::vec2(0, 0);
        uv4 = glm::vec2(0, height[1]);
    }

    float add = (1.0 / double(_tex_atlas_width)) * tex_num;
    uv1.x += add;
    uv2.x += add;
    uv3.x += add;
    uv4.x += add;

    // triangle 1
    _triangles.push_back(corner3); 
    _triangles.push_back(corner2); 
    _triangles.push_back(corner1); 

    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);

    _uvs.push_back(uv1);
    _uvs.push_back(uv2);
    _uvs.push_back(uv3);

    _indices.push_back(glm::vec3(nrOfIndices + 0, nrOfIndices + 1, nrOfIndices + 2));

    // triangle 2 
    //_triangles.push_back(corner1); 
    _triangles.push_back(corner4); 
    //_triangles.push_back(corner3); 

    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);

    _uvs.push_back(uv3);
    _uvs.push_back(uv4);
    _uvs.push_back(uv1);

    _indices.push_back(glm::vec3(nrOfIndices + 2, nrOfIndices + 3, nrOfIndices + 0));

    nrOfIndices += 4;

}
```

everything worked perfectly until I tried to add indices. What's wrong with it? I double checked the order of the indices and they seem to be correct, so I'm guessing it's an error with how I'm loading the indices, but I just can't figure it out with what I could find on learnopengl and other opengl documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). See [Index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers).

The instruction

> ```cpp
> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _IndiceID);
> ```

associates `_IndiceID` to the current Vertex Array Object.

You've to bind the Vertex Array Object, before you specify the element array buffer:

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_VAO);
glBindVertexArray(_VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _IndiceID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    _indices.size() * 3 * sizeof(GLuint),
    _indices.data(),
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Note, also the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is stated in the state vector of the VAO, but this happens when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called.
When `glVertexAttribPointer` is called, then the buffer which is currently bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the vertex attribute with the specified index.

The difference in the behavior of `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is caused, because a VAO can only refer to 1 index (element) buffer, but it can refer to multiple array buffers. Each attribute (index) can be associated to a different buffer.

---

Further more the data type of the indices has to be integral. Possible data types are (`unsigned`) `char`, `short` respectively `int`, which correspond to the OpenGL enumerator constants `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. See [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml)

Change the index vector and use `glm::ivec3` rather than `glm::vec3`

```cpp
std::vector<glm::ivec3> _indices;
```

```cpp
_indices.push_back(glm::ivec3(nrOfIndices + 2, nrOfIndices + 3, nrOfIndices + 0));
```

```cpp
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _indices.size()*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, and did the indicing after I introduce the VAO. The opengl error isn't appearing anymore, but still, no vertices or faces are being drawn when I run the program.

Comment: @HeartUnder8lade The indices have to be an integral data type. Use `glm::ivec3` rather than `glm::vec3`

Comment: Nice! The triangles all load in now! The textures were initially all messed up because of indicing, but I just removed the duplicate vertices of those and now they're fixed as well. Thanks!